# MKL Error DGEMM wrong entry

Tags: matlab, mex, lapack, blas, worhp

I have some problems with MATLAB and mkl. When I compile a mexfile and link it against an external optimisation library (called "worhp"), I get the following runtime error:

```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 5 was incorrect on entry to DGEMM.
```

When I compile and run my code outside MATLAB, I do not get this error.
I guess it has something to do with MATLAB specific blas and lapack  distributions.

Can I remove this error if I could force MATLAB to use system specific distributions of these libs?

I am working with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I know nought about mex/BLAS/LAPACK, but what I do know is that it is very difficult to change anything under the hood of MATLAB (experience with LaTeX packages). Therefore it might be easier to change your mex code to work with the BLAS/LAPACK version MATLAB uses.

Comment: it looks like your matrices are not understood in the right C order or F order. 5th parameter of DGEMM is the col number of A and row number of B.

Comment: I agree. I wonder if there is a way to tell matlab to use the system's libraries : /

Answer (score 0):

When you are compiling and running your code from outside MATLAB what BLAS/LAPACK are you linking against?

The parameter number 5 for `DGEMM` is the number of columns of `A` and rows of `B` in `A * B`, which obviously have to match; Depending on if you are linking against the Fortran (`extern "C" DGEMM`) routines or the c/c++ bindings (`cblas_dgemm`) you need to pass that value as an `int` or `int*`.

FORTRAN bindings:

```
extern void dgemm_(char*, char*, int*, int*,int*, double*, double*, int*, double*, int*, double*, double*, int*);
```

C bindings(MKL):

```
void cblas_dgemm (const char, const char, const char, const int m, const int n, const int, const double*, const double*, const int lda, const double*, const int, const double, double*, constint ldc);
```